Is it possible to create dimensional OLAP tables and an ETL process within an existing OLTP Postgres database?
I am a backend (mostly Go) developer working on a point-of-sale adjacent platform that processes and stores millions of orders and adjacent customer data into a Postgres database. The data is well normalized, but also unintuitive, poorly indexed, and inconsistent.
I have recently been tasked with generating a series of report, as well as dashboard metrics, that can be used to analyze sales data over time (for a new customer). With report generation, performance thus far has been a huge issue in production. Order tables are huge and require several joins to aggregate required data. We have made a lot of improvements with indexing and query structure to get report generation times down; However, while using our OLTP database tables directly has been possible for asynchronously requested reports, I know this isn't going to work for smaller dashboard metrics (e.g. orders per day, average sales per day, sales per location) that are expected to work in real time, and frequently refreshed, for a dashboard page.
I don't have experience working on these types of solutions, but I was encouraged to spend time diving into Kimball Group's "Dimensional Modeling Techniques", the concepts of data warehousing, OLAP vs. OLTP databases, etc., and have become convinced we need to make a move in that direction to solve these reporting/dashboard problems.
I don't know where to begin with what infrastructure, tooling, etc. would be required to implement/house my dimensional models, write an incremental (every 15 minutes) ETL pipeline from our existing transactional database, and make that data accessible for our front-end developers to write a dashboard.
I have been encouraged to try first implementing my dimensional tables within our existing Postgres database, then creating a periodic job that would upsert order data into the dimensional model every 15 minutes. Database performance under load will still be a concern, but these lightweight, pre-aggregated tables should be a lot faster to read from than our current ones.
Is this a reasonable approach? My main concern is that the periodic ETL job will involve very expensive queries (similar to those uses in our reports), and the complexities involve in keeping the dimensional tables up to date (what if an order record comes in late? what if underlying data changes? how do I prevent double-importing records?).
Does SQL have any useful features I should research that might help with these challenges? I'm fairly new to databases as well (come from an embedded system background), and we are using an archaic version of Postgres (9.6) for reasons I won't get into.

Yes you can do this, no problem. But your biggest problem is that lack of maintenance, you're years behind in maintenance. I would fix that issue first, before anything else. There is imho no point in building new functionalities on an unsupported foundation that is years behind in maintenance.

@FrankHeikens in reference to the outdated Postgres instances? 100% agree. Unfortunately, out of my control, but it is a scheduled priority. It just limits which features I have access to right now.

Building something new on an outdated platform makes the migration more difficult. More data, more functionality to test, etc. A lot of things have changed between versions 9.6 and 16. Things that work in 9.6, will not work in 16. That's why I wouldn't do it now, only after the migration. I see it as a waste of time to develop for 9.6

You can certainly build a data warehouse in PostgreSQL, but your question is too generic to answer. For an incremental ETL process, you need to be able to identify the changes since the last run, which is a problem of application design.
